# Slack webhooks cause cls-hooked request context to orphan mysql connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, slack-api, cls-hooked

**The main issue:**
We have a lovely little express app, which has been crushing it for months with no issues. We manage our DB connections by opening a connection on demand, but then caching it "per request" using the [cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked) library. Upon the request ending, we release the connection so our connection pool doesn't run out. Classic. Over the course of months and many connections, we've never "leaked" connections. Until now! Enter... slack! We are using the slack event handler as follows:

```
app.use('/webhooks/slack', slackEventHandler.expressMiddleware());
```

and we sort of *think* of it like any other request, however slack requests seem to play weirdly with our cls-hooked usage. For example, we use node-ts and nodemon to run our app locally (e.g. you change code, the app restarts automatically). Every time the app restarts locally on our dev machines, and you try and play with slack events, suddenly when our middleware that releases the connection tries to do so, it thinks there is nothing in session. When you then use a normal endpoint... it works fine and essentially seems to *reset* slack to working okay again. We are now scared to go to prod with our slack integration, because we're worried our slack "requests" are going to starve our connection pool.

**Background**

*Relevant subset of our package.json:*

```
{
  "@slack/events-api": "^2.3.2",
  "@slack/web-api": "^5.8.0",
  "express": "~4.16.1",
  "cls-hooked": "^4.2.2",
  "mysql2": "^2.0.0",
}
```

*The middleware that makes the cls-hooked session*

```
import { session } from '../db';

const context = (req, res, next) => {
  session.run(() => {
    session.bindEmitter(req);
    session.bindEmitter(res);
    next();
  });
};

export default context;
```

*The middleware that releases our connections*

```
export const dbReleaseMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', async () => {
    const conn = session.get('conn');
    if (conn) {
      incrementConnsReleased();
      await conn.release();
    }
  });
  next();
};
```

*the code that creates the connection on demand and stores it in "session"*

```
  const poolConn = await pool.getConnection();
  if (session.active) {
    session.set('conn', poolConn);
  }
  return poolConn;
```

*the code that sets up the session in the first place*

```
export const session = clsHooked.createNamespace('our_company_name');
```

If you got this far, congrats. Any help appreciated!

Side note: you couldn't pay me to write a more confusing title...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It seems we have identified the following behavior in the node version of slack's API (seems to only happen on mac computers... *sometimes*)

The issue is that this is in the context of an express app, so Slack is managing the interface between its own event handler system + the http side of things with express (e.g. returning 200, or 500, or whatever). So what seems to happen is...

```
// you have some slack event handler
slackEventHandler.on('message', async (rawEvent: any) => {
  const i = 0;
  i = i + 1;
  // at this point, the http request has not returned 200, it is "pending" from express's POV
  await myService.someMethod();
  // ^^ while this was doing its async thing, the express request returned 200.
  // so things like res.on('finished') all fired and all your middleware happened
  // but your event handler code is still going
});
```

So we ended up creating a manual call to release connections in our slack event handlers. Weird!